# How to verify patches installed properly on Magento locally

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, patches

I have upgraded my magento site from `1.7` to `1.9.2`.On Magento site this version shows have patches included `( Includes patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285, SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788 )`.I have done this work on local machine.I am trying to know that how can i verify that it have these patches  as i can see the message on admin side.I check the `app/etc` but didn't find any patches list file there.Can anyone suggest how can i know that its have these patches .I also install `Philwinklw_Appliedpatches` module but that did't show anything on admin side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally with successful patches, `app/etc/applied.patches.list` is updated.  This is the same file the `Philewinkle_Appliedpatches` module reads:

- https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_AppliedPatches/blob/master/app/code/community/Philwinkle/AppliedPatches/Model/Patches.php#L66

You can also view the contents of the `.sh` file and towards the bottom of the file you will see the difference or patch file data.  Using this you can compare the files that were changed and what line(s) etc. were modified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but sorry to say that i didnt get it completely.Where is the `.sh` file ?

Comment: Usually the patches Magento releases are `.sh` scripts: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html how did you apply the patch(es) ?

Comment: I only installed the Magento 1.9.2 and on magento  on the site its shows `https://www.magentocommerce.com/download` that this version have these patches included.So i thought its already added

Comment: If you downloaded and installed a new copy of 1.9.2 from Magento's download all patches are already included. Note the `Full Releases` tab on the download page: `- Includes patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285, SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788`

Comment: Yes i have downloaded that that why i was trying to know.Ok means no worries to verify.I downloaded it previous day and upgraded today.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

3 options (I know of)

1. Take a look in app/etc/applied.patches.list
2. Compare the code itself (look into patch script and compare it to your installation and check if the files got patched)
3. Run a scan on https://www.magereport.com/